# Error: Returned error: sender account not recognized

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, nodejs, ganache

this contract for Deploys instances of other smart contracts and i'm using ganache

```
contract Contracts_Factory {
    // Common Section
    uint256 SIZE = 10;
    uint index = 0;
    string[] accounts = [
        "0x86d9Cd9A9F7263367fc232110CE987cF654DcF28",
        "0x6F746B2C11b766b813ae80AF50B7ff7244f53E7B",
        "0x12910F86889f796aC677BF70a5Da0C25d3485338",
        "0xae6AC0D3A3c8Aa519004163f969D32ee859c4e4c",
        "0x763EF7E590F979563cB598e21E9e45495C86a715",
        "0x47b57fAf1CEee1eC78F2C182f0e75AeE826D72E5",
        "0x47b57fAf1CEee1eC78F2C182f0e75AeE826D72E5",
        "0x7dD0D6eC2FE74A79A119F8d648bEE5C5d48CC53e",
        "0x87ccbFF8dA543CE840f7b7324da8c1e9ccEf4d33",
        "0x41Cc6B410264B37ef3cF629700F26253FF36afe9"
    ];




function getEthAccount() public view returns (string[] memory) {
    return accounts;
}

function getIndex() public view returns (uint) {
    return index;
}

function incrementIndex() public {
    index++;
}

// Manufacturer Section
int256 _manufacturer_SIZE = 0;
Manufacturer[] _manufacturers;

function createManufacturer() public {
    Manufacturer newManufacturer = new Manufacturer();
    _manufacturers.push(newManufacturer);
    _manufacturer_SIZE++;
}

function allManufacturers() public view returns (Manufacturer[] memory) {
    return _manufacturers;
}

function get_manufacturer_SIZE() public view returns (int256) {
    return _manufacturer_SIZE;
}

// Distributor Section
int256 _distributor_SIZE = 0;
Distributor[] _distributors;

function createDistributor() public {
    Distributor newdistributor = new Distributor();
    _distributors.push(newdistributor);
    _distributor_SIZE++;
}

function allDistributors() public view returns (Distributor[] memory) {
    return _distributors;
}

function get_distributor_SIZE() public view returns (int256) {
    return _distributor_SIZE;
}

// Retailer Section
int256 _retailer_SIZE = 0;
Retailer[] _retailers;

function createRetailer() public {
    Retailer newRetailer = new Retailer();
    _retailers.push(newRetailer);
    _retailer_SIZE++;
}

function allRetailers() public view returns (Retailer[] memory) {
    return _retailers;
}

function get_retailer_SIZE() public view returns (int256) {
    return _retailer_SIZE;
}

// Customer Section
int256 _customer_SIZE = 0;
Customer[] _customers;

function createCustomer() public {
    Customer newManufacturer = new Customer();
    _customers.push(newManufacturer);
    _customer_SIZE++;
}

function allCustomers() public view returns (Customer[] memory) {
    return _customers;
}

function get_customer_SIZE() public view returns (int256) {
    return _customer_SIZE;
}

// Product Section
int256 _product_SIZE = 0;
Product[] _products;

function createProduct(string memory _owner) public {
    Product newProduct = new Product(_owner);
    _products.push(newProduct);
    _product_SIZE++;
}

function allProducts() public view returns (Product[] memory) {
    return _products;
}

function get_product_SIZE() public view returns (int256) {
    return _product_SIZE;
}

// Transport Section
int256 _transport_SIZE = 0;
Transport[] _transports;

function createTransport(string memory _owner) public {
    Transport newTransport = new Transport(_owner);
    _transports.push(newTransport);
    _transport_SIZE++;
}

function allTransports() public view returns (Transport[] memory) {
    return _transports;
}

function get_transport_SIZE() public view returns (int256) {
    return _transport_SIZE;
    }
}
```

and this the code of the server side

```
router.post('/setup-raw-material-request', async (req, res) => {

// html form only contains Product name here

const user = req.cookies.accessToken; // accessing cookie

// created a new contract for product
// user.ContractAddress is owner

await factory.createProduct(user.ContractAddress, { from: process.env.defaultAccount }); 
const index = await factory.get_product_SIZE();
const allProducts = await factory.allProducts();
const ContractAddress = allProducts[index - 1];
const productContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(product_ABI, ContractAddress); // product

console.log(req.body.Product)
console.log(user.ContractAddress)
// access the product details from database and create a request for each one
db.product.findOne({ Product: req.body.Product , Owner : user.ContractAddress}).then(async (result) => {

    console.log(result)
    // setup request // accepted request by manufacturer // raw material with distributor // raw material received

    if (result) {

        result.Requirement.forEach(async (element) => {
            await db.productRequest.create({
                Product: ContractAddress,
                Owner: user.ContractAddress,
                Material: element._material,
                Capacity: element._capacity,
                Price: element._price,
                currentOwner: user.ContractAddress,
                Status: "Request-raised",
            })
            // console.log(user.ContractAddress)
            // console.log(user.eth_A)
            // console.log(ContractAddress)

            // sent money to the smart contract for material price
            await web3.eth.sendTransaction({ from: user.eth_Account, to: ContractAddress, value: element._price });

            await productContract.methods.setRequests(element._material).send({ from: process.env.defaultAccount });

        });

        // res.send({ Success: true })
        res.redirect('/retailer-page');
    }
    else
        res.redirect('/retailer-page');
        // return res.send({ Success: false })
})

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "Returned error: sender account not recognized" occurs when the account you are using to send a transaction is not recognized by the network. This can happen when you are using an incorrect account address or when the account you are using does not have sufficient funds to send the transaction.

In your case, it is possible that the `process.env.defaultAccount` is not set to a valid Ethereum account or that the account does not have enough funds to execute the transaction. You can check if the `process.env.defaultAccount` is set correctly and if the account has enough funds to send the transaction. Additionally, you can try using a different Ethereum account to send the transaction and see if the error persists.

Comment: thanks, the account I'm using does not have sufficient funds to send the transaction.